# How to use the node js client library with express?

Tags: express, actions-on-google

I have implemented a dialogFlow fulfillment without using the node js client library. I have been parsing requests and preparing responses manually. Now, I wanted to start using the node js client library, as found here: https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/

I am using the express framework as generated by the express generator.
Here is some of the contents of my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var smarthome5 = require('./routes/smarthome5');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use('/smarthome5',smarthome5);
module.exports = app;
```

my ./routes/smarthome5 contains these:

```
const express = require('express')
var router = express.Router();
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google')

const dfApp = dialogflow()
router.post('/', dfApp)

// Register handlers for Dialogflow intents
dfApp.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask('Hi, how is it going?')
  conv.ask(`Here's a picture of a cat`)
})

// Intent in Dialogflow called `Goodbye`
dfApp.intent('Goodbye', conv => {
  conv.close('See you later!')
})

dfApp.intent('Default Fallback Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask(`I didn't understand. Can you tell me something else?`)
})

module.exports = router;
```

However, when I run the code and make a POST request to /smarthome5, I get an error like so:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at new User (/app/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/actionssdk/conversation/user.js:75:43)
at new Conversation (/app/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/actionssdk/conversation/conversation.js:73:21)
at new DialogflowConversation (/app/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/conv.js:38:9)
at Function.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:113:24)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at /app/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:22:71
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at __awaiter (/app/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:18:12)
at Function.handler (/app/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:84:16)
```

when I try replacing the post handler in ./routes/smarthome5 with this:

```js
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('POST ' + __filename);
    console.dir(req.body, {depth: null});
})
```

I am able to see the POST request. So my routes are working it's just that I do not know if I am using the dfApp correctly.

[sample post request body and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i24YN.png)

[Request body 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3xNV.png)

[originalDetectIntentRequest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQCHO.png)

[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUyaK.png)

[userStorage Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLKCa.png)

Comment: Can you show the req.body contents? (Or at lest the first few characters of it?)

Comment: I've edited my post to include that :)

Comment: That shows the headers, but not the body. Since the error is with the JSON body, somehow, we need to see that to help figure out what is going on.

Comment: My bad. I have included a snapshot of the first part of the request body

Comment: Ok, that is a good sign, at least. Can you include the part of the request body under `originalDetectIntentRequest` that includes the `user` object?

Comment: I have added originalDetectIntentRequest. Thanks for helping me out, I'm really stuck here.

Comment: You actually ended up masking one of the fields that is relevant in this case. {: Is the value in userStorage a JSON string? Or is it a value you have there that is not JSON formatted? (Does it start with a { or does it start with a number?)

Comment: I have attached the contents of the userStorage field. I believe it is the UUID I have generated from the webhook. It's an alternative way that I saw in order to identify users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your userStorage has been set to a string. The library assumes that this string is JSON and attempts to decode it. However, the library fails to handle when it isn't (likely because it ensures it is JSON when it saves it).

Fixing this will be difficult. If the code was in production, you can view and clear the user storage, but this isn't available before it is listed in the directory. You can clear the user storage in code - but this error is happening when it initializes the request, so you need to do this first. (And you **only** need to do this the first time for each user you've tested with.) In the line `router.post('/', dfApp)`, instead of calling the `dfApp` function directly, call a function that modifies `req.body` to remove or reset that field from the JSON. I haven't tested, but possibly something like

```
router.post('/', function( req, res ){
  req.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.user.userStorage='{}';
  dfApp( req, res );
});
```

If you really need to preserve that ID (instead of just generating a new one), you can do so there as well, but make sure the string is a valid JSON string.

Going forward, you should treat `conv.user.storage` as an object. Storing a user ID there would be done with something like

```
conv.user.storage.id = generateId();
```

(Or pick some attribute name that works for you.)

Comment: Woah! This looks promising. I will try this out! Thanks.

Comment: Hope it helps! If so, accepting and/or upvoting the answer are always appreciated.

Comment: YOU'RE THE MAN!!
I just had the time to test it today. And it super works!! Thanks a lot, man! Super! as it turns out, the error message is on-spot. Thanks. thanks! (my upvote doesn't seem to get counted yet)

Answer (score 1):

The Actions-On-Google NodeJS client's Github pages show different ways to build your agent. There is also a code snippet showing the use of Express to develop a webhook. Check out the Readme [here](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs). It is all covered.

**UPDATE**
here you have it

```
'use strict';

const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = dialogflow();

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
    conv.ask('Hi, Welcome to Assistant by Express JS ');
});

express().use(bodyParser.json(), app).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Thanks. That link is what I've been following all along. But as I am new to node js and express, I can't seem to be following it correctly.
Am is using this correctly?
`const dfApp = dialogflow()`

Comment: Thanks!
When using express in node js, would that be equivalent to:
     `const express = require('express')
     var router = express.Router();
     const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google')
const dfApp = dialogflow() 
    router.post('/', dfApp) 
    module.exports = router;`

Comment: My express back-end does some other things. That is why I was making use of routes. In my original posts, I have a very similar code as your update. But it doesn't work :(

Comment: did you check the following https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/issues/118. One example is using router

Comment: Yeah. I did. I came across that while looking for possible solutions. It produces the same error :(